# UIScrollView's subview is visible but not touchable

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview

There is some viewController (In code "controller")  that works fine.

ViewController has a view witch size can be change in runtime so I need use scrollView to display it all properly.

I add a view to the scrollView (in special created class) and it works just fine in portrait mode: I can change content of added view and see how it scrolls.

But in landscape mode there is unknown problem: I can see the view but it like a background - can see but can't touch it.

I do not rotate, I create views exactly in portrait or landscape mode. I create views same way both time.

```
ScrollForModalView* scrollController = [[ScrollForModalView alloc] init];
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ScrollForModalView" owner:scrollController      
options:nil];       

scrollController.scrollView.contentSize = 
CGSizeMake(controller.view.frame.size.width, controller.view.frame.size.height);

[scrollController.scrollView addSubview:controller.view];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]    
initWithRootViewController:scrollController];
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

[navController release];
[scrollController release];
```

Haven't any clue what to do.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was the problem, but it disappear when I set in InterfaceBuilder -> simulated User Interface Elements -> Orientation to Landscape for the view containing scrollView.